# Locker room procedure

Tags: gym

Is it normal for people to walk around the locker room completely nude and also sit there texting letting the penis and balls go where ever they want?

Comment: Not sure this has anything to do with fitness. It's more about someone's expectations.

Comment: @rrirower - Agreed. I wrote an answer because I think it's important that we don't stigmatise people for their behaviour in the locker room. It's a place to get naked, and if you want to air dry, that's your choice. But etiquette regarding physical distance should be respected.

Comment: This should have been marked as a duplicate: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/5032/7091

Answer (score 3):

Normal? Yes and no. It's about people and their preferences, not procedure.

Etiquette? No rules against it.

Don't like it? Get over it.

"letting the penis and balls go where ever they want" is just you exaggerating. So long as they're not touching you, they're not doing anything wrong. It's a locker room! They're allowed to be as naked as they please.

If they're getting uncomfortably close to you, let them know. Other than that, deal with it.

Comment: I think it can also depend on the management / specific circumstances. I currently go to a gym where nudity in the locker room is fine, but I've also been a member at another gym where the lockers were out in the open and only had individual shower / changing rooms. In that case I don't think the 'locker room' would be an appropriate place to be nude.

Comment: "So long as they're not touching you" covers a *lot* of ground :/